# debootstrap or virt-install Ubuntu Server Maverick fails

Tags: server, virtualization, debootstrap, container, vps

Running any kind of variation of debootstrap, I get the following error:

> I: Extracting zlib1g...
> W: Failure trying to run: chroot /lxc/iso/dodo mount -t proc proc /proc

debootstrap.log :

```
mount: permission denied
```

If I manually `chroot` into the directory, then I am prompted with:

> ```
> id: cannot find name for group ID 0
> ```

I have no name!

I tried `addgroup` but it's not installed, `apt-get/aptitude : command not found`, so I can't do anything with it.

I've tried `ubuntu-vm-builder`, but since it's calling debootstrap, I get the same error.

I played with it for a few days, then I stopped and gave virt-install a try. Everything works until I get to the console to finish the install which only shows:

> Escape character is ^]

and nothing more, no matter what I type.

So basically what I'm trying to do is build a usable `chroot` system so that I can use it with lxc or libvirt.

What are my options to get containers/virtualisation up and running? I've read somewhere that I can use openvz templates with lxc or libvirt. How can I do this?

I'm doing all this on a dedicated server, so I can't access it by hand, only ssh, plus on my local pc running Ubuntu Desktop Maverick everything works.

EDIT

Getting closer, I managed to understand how to use an openvz template with lxc, now the problem comes with the network bridge:

> ```
> lxc-start: invalid interface name: br0 # Use same bridge device used in your controlling host setup
> lxc-start: failed to process 'lxc.network.link = br0 # Use same bridge device used in your controlling host setup'
> lxc-start: failed to read configuration file
> ```

I followed the exact steps to create a bridge and lxc conf looks like:

```
lxc.network.type = veth
lxc.network.flags = up
lxc.network.link = br0 # Use same bridge device used in your controlling host setup
lxc.network.hwaddr =  {a1:b2:c3:d4:e5:f6} # As appropiate (line only needed if you wish to dhcp later)
lxc.network.ipv4 = {10.0.0.100} # (Use 0.0.0.0 if you wish to dhcp later)
lxc.network.name = eth0 # could likely be whatever you want
```

Since it's not working, I know smth is wrong so could somebody guide me ?

EDIT: looks like the base install was using a custom kernel (bzImage-2.6.34.6-xxxx-grs-ipv6-65) for which I didn't find the headers. I did an `update-grub` after I installed a new kernel, edited menu.lst and now it's using 2.6.35-23-server and now debootstrap is working just fine (same as ubuntu-vm-builder).

Comment: you have about five different questions there.  Please post one question per different approach that you're trying.

Comment: indeed i'm asking too many questions in one post , however my goal is to get a virtual machine working inside my dedicated server , i realy don't care witch technology will be used , since none works i suspect the problem is in the same place for both aproaches .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command worked for me:

```
sudo lxc-create -n my-vm -t ubuntu
```

but I didn't generally find that lxc was very mature.  Using kvm:

```
vm-builder kvm ubuntu
```

Perhaps the simplest solution is: download an Ubuntu ISO, run virt-manager, create a VM through the GUI, attach the ISO to the CD drive, then boot it and install in the usual way.

Comment: i'm doing this on a dedicated server i can't access any GUI tools just plain old console